# List and folder of the combination of json and jpeg from S3

Tags: json, python-3.x, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In a S3 bucket, there are 10 files which I want to access. Like below:

- `1.jpeg`
- `1.json`
- `2.jpeg`
- `2.json`
- `3.jpeg`
- `3.json`
- `4.jpeg`
- `5.jpeg`
- `6.jpeg`
- `7.jpeg`

For each `json` file, there is a corresponding `jpeg` file.

I want to separate these as 3 lists of files and download in to 3 folders.

Folder One is `json` with files

```
1.json
2.json
3.json
```

Second folder contains associated images

```
1.jpeg
2.jpeg
3.jpeg
```

Third folder contains only images without corresponding json

```
4.jpeg
5.jpeg
6.jpeg
7.jpeg
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you done already for this ? People can help you in fixing the problems in your approach or code which you already did.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this within your Python code:

```py
objects = ['1.jpeg', '1.json', '2.jpeg', '2.json', '3.jpeg', '3.json', '4.jpeg', '5.jpeg', '6.jpeg', '7.jpeg']

# All .json keys
json_list = [key for key in objects if key.endswith('.json')]

# All .jpeg keys that match the .json keys
matching_jpeg_list = [key for key in objects if key.endswith('.jpeg') and key.replace('.jpeg', '.json') in json_list]

# All .jpeg keys that do NOT match .json keys
mismatched_jpeg_list = [key for key in objects if key.endswith('.jpeg') and key not in matching_jpeg_list]

print('json list:', json_list)
print('matching jpeg list:', matching_jpeg_list)
print('mismatched jpeg list', mismatched_jpeg_list)
```